# Creating a zip archieve

Tags: zip

I want to create a zip archive from all files which are in "my_folder". Here is how I do it:

```
zip -9 -y -r -q  name.zip /home/user/Stack_Exchange/my_folder/
```

The problem is that right now when I unpack the archive, the hierarchy of folders is fixed, so the result of unpacking is the home folder and inside is the user folder, etc.

How can I create a zip archive which has only "my_folder" in the directory? I mean I want to see the folder "my_folder" after unpacking the archive.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `-j` option

From `man zip`

> You may want to make a zip archive that contains the files in foo, without recording the directory name, foo.  You can use the -j option to leave off the paths, as in:
>
> zip -j foo foo/*

new command will be:

```
zip -9 -y -r -q -j  name.zip /home/user/Stack_Exchange/my_folder/
```

Comment: Won't this strip `my_folder` as well ? I think OP want `my_folder/*` , but not `/home/user/Stack_Exchange/my_folder/*`

Answer (score 0):

Make the .zip file while in the directory above my_folder

e.g.

```
cd /home/user/Stack_Exchange
zip -9 -y -r -q  name.zip ./my_folder/
```